# Videoview stoped playing video after pressing back and home button

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am trying to play video in `Videoview`, video play is stopped when I press back or home button. My code in `onCreate()`

```
Videoview videoview= findViewById(R.id.videoview);
Uri uri = android.net.Uri.parse("xxxx.xxxx");
videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
videoview.start();
```

Comment: who would be watching the video if it plays in background?

Comment: I want to listen audio.

Comment: probably it understands that it's `Surface` has been destroyed or paused. You probably need to use SurfaceView + MediaPlayer

Comment: I wish YouTube did that. I would only listen to audio.